# There exist a function such that $f\circ f(x)=e^x$?

Tags: real-analysis

Based on this question: [How to calculate $f(x)$ in $f(f(x)) = e^x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59023/how-to-calculate-fx-in-ffx-ex)
I would like to know if I can get a function such that $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb  R^+$, defined by $f\circ f(x)=e^x$. My guess is no, but I can't prove it, I need help.

Note that different than the previous question, the function is from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R^+$.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I did this before. My result is that you can have a bunch of functions satisfy this formula, hint is that this fucntion must be strictly monotone, and you just need to define it on a little interval to get the whole function.

Comment: @lee sorry it misses informations, I'm going to edit my question

Comment: It appears [this question has been asked before on math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/59023/264), so this question will be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @ZevChonoles My question is defined differently than other posts.

Answer (score 4):

In fact, you can find such an $f$ that is analytic. From [this answer on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17614/solving-ffxgx/24856#24856):

> A real-analytic solution in this case was constructed by H. Kneser, "Reelle analytische Lösungen der Gleichung $φ(φ(x))=e^x$ und verwandter Funktional-gleichungen", *J. Reine Angew. Math.* 187 (1949), 56-67.

I'm afraid I don't know the details of the construction, but hopefully this reference is helpful.

Other relevant threads:

- [Does the exponential function have a square root?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12081)
- [Square root of a function (in the sense of composition)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3633/264)
- [Characterising functions $f$ that can be written as $f = g \circ g$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1118/264)
- [The graph of $f(x)$ where $f(f(x))=e^x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/180248/264)

Comment: thank you for your answer, did you see my edition?