# Is there a continuous function on R such that $f(f(x))=e^{-x}$?

Tags: calculus

Is there a continuous function on R such that $f(f(x))=e^{-x}$? I have tried to take derivative of the two sides,but I can't get anything I want.what can I do?

Comment: Note $f(f(x))=e^x$ has been discussed at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65876/thoughts-about-ffx-ex and at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296745/there-exist-a-function-such-that-f-circ-fx-ex

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. *Hint:* An injective continuous function is monotonic and for any monotonic $f(x)$ the function $f(f(x))$ should be increasing.

Comment: This is only if f required to be real-valued. If it is allowed being complex-valued (but continuous and defined on R), it can exist.

Answer (score 0):

If the function f is allowed to take complex values on R, such function exists.