# Fractional logarithm operator

Tags: logarithms, fractional-calculus

Does there exist a fractional logarithm operator?

Something like this:

$$L_0(x) = x$$
$$L_1(x) = log(x)$$
$$L_{0.5}(x) = ???$$

This is the motivating situation: consider perception of sound, which is logarithmic. So a sequence of sounds with amplitude 1, 10, 100 is perceived to be linearly increasing in volume.

If we are plotting a spectrum, we wouldn't plot amplitude against frequency. This wouldn't look right as per our perception. A little bump next to a mountain, it would look as though that should be discarded. But that bump is audible. Taking logarithms, that bump now becomes visually significant.

If I could take a $L_{1.5}(\cdot)$ fractional logarithm, it would increase the prominence of these minor features further.

Maybe I can consider an analogy with powers.  Between $x$ and $x^2$ we can have $f(x)$ such that $f_2(x) = f(f(x)) = x^2$.

hmm no I am stuck!

PS if anyone can suggest a mapping that accomplishes what I'm after, please do suggest, even if it doesn't directly answer the original question!

Comment: So basically you are talking about [fractional iterates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function#Fractional_iterates_and_flows.2C_and_negative_iterates), in particular about the [functional square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_square_root) of the natural logarithm, which is the inverse of the [half-exponential function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-exponential_function). A simple Google search for these terms also reveals [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3633) article.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean here, but the half derivative of the natural logarithm is known: $$\frac{d^{1/2}}{dx^{1/2}}\ln(x)=\frac{\ln(4x)}{\sqrt{\pi x}}$$