# $f(f(x)) = 1 + x^2$, then what is f(1)?

Tags: functions, functional-equations

I get $f(f(a)) = a^2 + 1 = f(f(-a))$, and so $f(a)^2 + 1 = f(a^2 + 1) = f(-a)^2 + 1$, so $f(a) = f(-a)$ or $f(a) = -f(-a)$, but then I donot know what to do next. Thanks for any help.

Comment: If one could read Chinese or use a translator, there's this same discussion on Zhihu: https://www.zhihu.com/question/340104755

Comment: Above link shows how to construct a solution of the given functional equation. In fact there is a construction in English also. But I don't see uniqueness there. Is it clear from that post that $f(1)$ is uniquely determined?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Ah no, the second highest voted answer in the same thread showed that if we drop analyticity of $f$ then it's anywhere in $(1,5)\setminus\{2\}$

Comment: OP should provide some context. If $f(1)$ cannot be determined uniquely by the given equation I don't think this question is appropriate.

Comment: See https://www.jstor.org/stable/2321556?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents.

Comment: What are the domain and codomain of $f$ supposed to be?  $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1612308/if-ffx-x2-1-then-f6 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3633/on-the-functional-square-root-of-x21

Answer (score 1):

A piece of information is still required

$f(f(x)) = 1+x^2$

Let's say $y = f(x)$ is the function, then $y = g(x)$ is the inverse function

$f(x) = g(1+x^2)$, $f(1) = g(2)$

$f(f(x)) = 1+x^2 = f(f(-x))$
$f(f(x)) = f(f(-x))$
Therefore $f(x) = f(-x)$
$f(x)$ is a even function

$f(f(x)) = 1+x^2$, say $x → g(x)$

$f(x) = 1+g(x)^2$, $f(1) = 1+g(1)^2$

$1+g(x)^2 = g(1+x^2)$

Say $x → f(x)$
$1+x^2 = g(1+f(x)^2)$, $f(1+x^2) = 1+f(x)^2$

$f(x) = $

$1+f(x)^2 = f(1+x^2)$

I can't find $f(1)$ unless I knew $f(n)$

$f(1+x^2) = 1+f(x)^2$, Remember $f(x) = 1+g(x)^2$

$f(1+x^2) = 1+(g(x)^2+1)^2$, $f(1+x^2) = g(x)^4+2*g(x)^2+2$

Recall $f(x) = g(1+x^2)$, say $1+x^2→x$
$g(x) = f(\sqrt(x-1))$

$f(1+x^2) = f(\sqrt(x-1))^4+2*f(\sqrt(x-1))^2+2$