# Proving that if $m \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $\left]m,m+1\right[ = \emptyset$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Using the fact that $\mathbb{Z}$ is an ordered ring.

Is this the same as proving that $n>m \Leftrightarrow n \geq m+1$ (again, in $\mathbb{Z}$)? I take it that it is, but, I also have trouble proving that.

I'd appreciate any sort of guidance or hints.

Comment: Do you have available the fact that $\Bbb Z$ is a discrete ordered ring, i.e., that there is nothing strictly between $0$ and $1$?

Comment: You need more than just an ordered ring structure. $\mathbb{Q}$ is an ordered ring but it does not have this property.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, yes, I have that available. I know of a proof for that fact. How would one derive this proof from that?

Comment: @Rodrigo: Suppose that $m<x<m+1$ and add $-m$ to everything.

Comment: @Rodrigo You could do it inductively. Show no element exists between $1$ and $2$ (by subtracting $1$..) and so on.

Comment: @Rodrigo the point was more that you need an extra assumption to make it work since the order+ring properties are not enough, but Brian got it covered and you confirmed.

Comment: Yes, it was quite easy. Thanks a bunch, Brian and Cameron!

Comment: @Rodrigo: You’re welcome!

Comment: @Rodrigo Feel free to answer your own question so this post doesn't go unanswered and get bumped by Community for no reason :)

Comment: @Cameron It's part of a *characterization* of $\,\Bbb Z,\,$ viz. any ordered ring R whose positives P are well-ordered in R is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$ as an ordered ring. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/161357/242) for an easy proof.

Comment: @BillDubuque I'm aware. It's more that OP couldn't prove it since they were clearly overlooking the final piece of the puzzle.