# Showing that in a well ordered ring homomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, there are no elements between zero and the ring's identity.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, well-orders

I'd like to prove the following statement:

> Given a well-ordered ring $A\neq \emptyset$ with identity $I$ and a
>   homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{Z}\to A$ such that $\phi(n) = nI$, then
>   the set
>
> $$\left\{ a\in A: 0<a<I \right\}$$
>
> is empty.

If $\phi$ was surjective (or bijective), then this would obviously be true. (So, I suspect that that's the case.) But, how could I then prove that?

Comment: Exactly. Thanks for pointing that out. I've corrected it.

Comment: Must the well-ordering obey any rules related to the ring operations? If not, you have the ring of Gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, with a spiral ordering like $0 < i < 1+i < 1 < 1-i < -i < \cdots$

Comment: @aschepler Would it be a ring if it didn't obey the rules defined for rings? Can we say that $i<1$?

Comment: Given that well-ordering of the set $\{a+bi ; a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ independently of the ring, sure we can have $i<1$. But it would be very reasonable to say that "well-ordered ring" means ["ordered ring"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_ring) plus "the total ordering is also a well-ordering", not just "ring" plus "well-ordering", just as "ordered ring" means more than "total order" plus "ring".

Comment: Same as in [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/161357/242)  in the linked dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll argue by contradiction.

Suppose that the set $S=\{x \in A :0<a<I\}$ is non-empty. Then, since $A$ is well-ordered, $S$ has a minimum element, let's call it $m$.

We know that $0 < m < I$, which means that $0 < m^2 < m < I$.

But now we found an element $m^2 \in S$ that is less than the minimum $m$, contradiction.

Thus, the set $S$ must be empty.

Comment: Is $m^2<m, \forall 0<m<I$ true in for all rings? If so, why?

Comment: What properties do you require for an ordering of a ring? This result should follow from them, but the exact details depend on the way things are defined.

Comment: I believe I follow the most widespread definition of ordered ring: $a+b,ab\in A^+,  \forall a,b\in A^+$ and that $\forall 0\neq a\in A$ we either have $a\in A^+$ or $-a\in A^+$.

Comment: @J.C. I wonder how we can conclude from the axioms of partially ordering that $a<b$ implies $ac<bc$? For example, in the ring $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$, it seems to be not valid.

Comment: @Rodrigo We know that $m \in A^+$ and $I-m \in A^+$, hence $m(I-m) = m - m^2 \in A^+$, which means $m^2<m$.

Comment: @FranzNietzche As far as I know, when speaking of ordered rings we usually require some properties like those in Rodrigo's comment, not just a bare partial order defined on the ring. In that sense $\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$ is not an ordered ring.

Comment: Could we have $0<m$ but $m^2=0$?

Comment: @aschepler The set of positive elements is closed under multiplication, by definition, so that cannot happen.

Comment: @J.C. Hmm, with Rodrigo's definition yes. But does that also follow from [Wikipedia's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_ring) $a \leq b \Rightarrow a+c \leq b+c$ and $0 \leq a \land 0 \leq b \Rightarrow 0 \leq a+b$?