# Oordinal numbers - lack of understanding of equality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$, 
can anyone explain me why:
$n+\omega=\omega$ and $n+\omega=\omega$.  It makes me crazy. can you explain it me ? For me, it should be $n+\omega = \omega+n$.

Comment: Check out this post http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49034/is-infinity-an-odd-or-even-number/49046#49046

Comment: You wrote "$n+\omega=\omega$ and $n+\omega=\omega$". Presumably you meant to write something else.

Comment: Why should ordinal addition be commutative necessarily?

Comment: This youtube video from vsauce explains it intuitively: https://youtu.be/SrU9YDoXE88?t=1386

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\omega +3$ looks like $$******\cdots **\,*$$ And $3+\omega $ looks like
$$*** \ \ ******\cdots$$ where the space is just for emphasis.

So look at the three things:

$$\begin{align*}
\omega: &******\cdots\\
3+\omega: &******\cdots\\
\omega+3: &******\cdots**\,*
\end{align*}$$

The first two pictures are the same the third is different.

And anyway what are oodinals ? Is it some kind of noodle ?

Comment: (Maybe they are nuumbers.)

Comment: Can you explain me what is ordinal number of $\left\{1-\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}\cup \left\{2\right\}$ ?

Comment: It is $\omega+1$.