# Any chance for a solution of $f[f(x)]=x^2+1$?

Tags: functional-equations

Not sure if this is a closed or open question. But the question is suppose $f[f(x)]=x^2+1$ then what is $f(x)$? Though the question does not refer to the domain let us suppose it is defined on $\Bbb R$.

Thanks.

Comment: Also [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118/characterising-functions-f-that-can-be-written-as-f-g-circ-g).