# Find every bijection of non-zero real numbers whose inverse is its reciprocal

Tags: analysis

Find all functions $f $: $\mathbb R^{×}$ $\to$ $\mathbb R^{×}$ that are one-to-one and
onto and such that $f^{−1}(x)= 1/ f(x)$, Where $\mathbb R^{×}=\mathbb R-${0}

My approach:=

At first I have consider $f(x)=x$ and $f(x)=1/x$ then this does not satisfy  $f^{−1}(x)= 1/ f(x)$

Now I am unable to construct such functions.

Comment: The condition can also be expressed as $f\left(\frac{1}{f(x)}\right)=x$ and $\ln(f^{-1}(x)) = - \ln(f(x))$. And if we consider a simple function of $g(x) = x + a$, we get the corresponding condition as $g^{-1}(x) = g(x) - 2a$. Maybe that will gives ideas for generating general functions?

Comment: I tried assuming a general power function $f(x) = x^p$, but got $p = i, -i \implies f(x) = e^{i \ln x}$, which is complex-valued for general $x$. So simple power function won't work.

Comment: If $f^{-1}(x) = 1/f(x)$, then $x = f^{-1}(f(x)) = 1/f(f(x))$, so this problem amounts to finding functions $f$ with $f(f(x)) = 1/x$. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118/characterising-functions-f-that-can-be-written-as-f-g-circ-g) seems relevant but probably not helpful, since you're working over an infinite set.

Comment: Are there any constraints with respect to continuity?

Comment: [More](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_square_root) on "functional square roots."

Comment: Updated my answer, Please see if its useful.

Comment: Suggested title edit: "Find all bijections of non-zero real numbers whose inverse is its reciprocal." What I love about this question is that it is essentially asking for which functions the superscript $-1$ notation is unambiguous.

Comment: @AnnieCarter Good idea but doesn't this mixture of plural and singular sound strange?

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes, it does. I was going for something a little more descriptive than the present title. Maybe "Find every bijection of non-zero real numbers whose inverse is its reciprocal."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if $f^{-1}(x) = 1/f(x)$, then we have $$x = f^{-1}(f(x)) = 1/f(f(x)),$$ which is equivalent to requiring $f(f(x)) = 1/x$. This means that every value of $x$ is periodic, belonging to a cycle of the form $$a \mapsto b \mapsto 1/a \mapsto 1/b \mapsto a.$$

Now if $a = \pm 1$, then $a = 1/a$ so we must have $1/b = f(1/a) = f(a) = b$. So such an $f$ will satisfy $f(1) = \pm 1$ and $f(-1) = \mp 1$. It then remains to describe $f(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0, 1, -1\}$.

Since $x \neq 1/x$ for $x \neq \pm 1$, every element of $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0, 1, -1\}$ occurs in a 4-cycle $\{a, b, 1/a, 1/b\}$. So let $A$ and $B$ be any uncountable subsets of $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0, 1, -1\}$ such that the four sets $A$, $B$, $A^{-1}$, and $B^{-1}$ partition $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0, 1, -1\}$, where $$A^{-1} = \{1/x\ |\ x \in A\},$$ and similarly for $B^{-1}$. Let $g\colon A \to B$ be any bijection. Having fixed $f(1) = c = \pm 1$, define $f \colon \mathbb{R}^\times \to \mathbb{R}^\times$ by
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
c & \text{if $x = 1$} \\
-c & \text{if $x = -1$} \\
g(x) & \text{if $x \in A$} \\
1/g^{-1}(x) & \text{if $x \in B$} \\
1/g(1/x) & \text{if $x \in A^{-1}$} \\
g^{-1}(1/x) & \text{if $x \in B^{-1}$} \\
\end{cases}
$$

An an example, you could take $A = (1, \infty)$, $B = (-\infty, -1)$, and $g(x) = -x$.

Note that each such tuple $(c, A, B, g)$ will give a suitable function $f$, and each such function $f$ arises from a tuple of this form (by choosing for each 4-cycle a "first" element $a$, and declaring $A$ to be the set of these elements), but multiple tuples may correspond to the same function.

Answer (score 5):

**Partial answer that gives a very large family of solutions:**

For any subset $A \subset ]0, +\infty[$, let's denote $A^{-1} = \left\lbrace \dfrac{1}{x} \mid x \in A \right\rbrace$.

Let $A$ be any subset of $]0, +\infty[$ satisfying the two following conditions : $$A \cap A^{-1} = \emptyset \quad \text{and} \quad A \cup A^{-1} = ]0, +\infty[ \setminus \lbrace 1 \rbrace$$

Let $\sigma : A \rightarrow A^{-1}$ be any bijection between $A$ and $A^{-1}$, and let $g : ]0, +\infty[ \rightarrow ]0, +\infty[$ be the bijection defined by

$$\forall x > 0, \quad g(x)= \left\lbrace \begin{array}{cl} \sigma(x) & \text{if } x \in A \\ \dfrac{1}{\sigma(1/x)} &\text{if } x \in A^{-1} \\ 1 & \text{if } x=1\end{array} \right.$$

Then the function $$f : x \longmapsto \left\lbrace  \begin{array}{cc} -g(x) & \text{if } x>0 \\  \dfrac{1}{g^{-1}(-x)}& \text{if } x<0\end{array}\right.$$

satisfies the condition.

---

For example, if $A = ]1, +\infty[$, and $\sigma : x \mapsto \dfrac{1}{x}$, one obtains the function
$$f : x \longmapsto \left\lbrace  \begin{array}{cc} -\dfrac{1}{x} & \text{if } x>0 \\  -x& \text{if } x<0\end{array}\right.$$

which is a solution.

Comment: I thought Bourbaki notation for open intervals was dead - it certainly should be.

Comment: Hi .. we need to satisfy $f(x) f^{-1}(x) = f(x) f(1/x) = 1$. In your general solution for $x>0$, we get $f(x)f(1/x) = g(x)g(1/x) = 1$. Not every $g$ will satisfy this. In my answer, i deduced a similar looking functions based on signs in your specific example. Please take a look. Please clarify in your answer, if needed.

Comment: @1729taxi In France, Bourbaki is God and we all are his prophets.

Comment: It is a consequence $f^{-1}(x) = f(1/x)$ is a consequence of $f^{-1}(x) = 1/f(x)$. Please see my answer for this.

Comment: Using $f(f(x)) = 1/x$, we get $f(f(f(x))) = 1/f(x)$ and using same we get $f(f(f(x))) = f(1/x)$. Just combine/group the composition in different ways

Comment: @Balajisb Ok, I see what I missed. I edited.

Comment: Nice definition +1.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Still a horrible notation that is either not recognised or totally ignored in most of the world. (a,b) is a hell of a lot better than ]a,b[

Comment: @1729taxi Thanks for your enlightened opinion, but I write maths as I want.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Calm down - if you want to write poorly then that is, of course, your choice. But the person you were replying to is obviously at an early stage of their maths development and answering in an archaic and poorly legible notation is not exactly helpful.

Comment: @1729taxi: I agree with your choice of notation, for what it's worth. But "Calm down" seems like possibly not the best way to convince someone. (Especially as it doesn't sound to me at least that they raised their "voice" too much.)

Comment: Incidentally, I had no idea that notation came from Bourbaki. Interesting!

Comment: I think you get the full family of solutions if you let $A, B \subseteq \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0, 1, -1\}$ be any uncountable sets such that $\{A, B, A^{-1}, B^{-1}\}$ partition $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0, 1, -1\}$. Let $g\colon A \to B$ be any bijection, and define $f$ so that it induces cycles $x \mapsto g(x) \mapsto 1/x \mapsto 1/g(x)$ (and $1 \mapsto \pm 1$, $-1 \mapsto \mp 1$). My $A, B$ are your $A, -A^{-1}$, but I'm not restricting $A$ to positive numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If $$f(x) = y$$ then,
$$f^{-1}(y) = x = 1/f(y) \implies f(f(x)) = 1/x$$

$$f(f(x)) = 1/x \implies f(f(f(x))) = 1/f(x) = f(1/x) $$

Hence $$f(x) f(1/x) = 1 = f(x) f^{-1}(x)$$
Hence $$f^{-1}(x) = f(1/x)$$

$$f(f^{-1}(x)) = x \implies f(f(1/x)) = x$$

So functions such that $f(f(1/x)) = x$ and $f(x)f(1/x) = 1$ is possible.

For $x>0$, let $$x = e^y \implies f(e^y) f(e^{-y}) = 1 \implies g(y)g(-y) = 1$$
where $g(y) = f(e^y)$.

So any solution is of the form:
$$g(y)g(-y) = 1$$.

An example:
$$g(y) = e^{-h(y)}$$
where $h(y)$ is any odd function.
So now, $$f(e^y) = e^{-h(y)} \implies f(x) = e^{-h(\ln(x))}.$$

Define:
$$For \ x>0, f(x) = -e^{h(\ln(|x|))}$$.
$$For \ x<0, f(x) = e^{-h(\ln(|x|))}$$.

Now check $$f(f(x)) = 1/x \implies f(f(x)) = e^{-h(\ln(|e^{h(\ln(x))}|))} = e^{-h(h(\ln(x)))} = 1/x$$
Hence $$h(h(\ln(x))) = \ln(x)$$

So any odd function of the form $h(h(y)) = y$ will work in:

$$For \ x>0, f(x) = -e^{h(\ln(|x|))}$$.
$$For \ x<0, f(x) = e^{-h(\ln(|x|))}$$.

The following are atleast possible: $h(y) = y$, $h(y)  = -y$ ,$h(y) = 1/y$,$h(y) = -1/y$.

Comment: This does not satisfy the given condition because $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{x}{c}$ and $1/f(x)=1/cx$.

Comment: Your $x$ and $y$ are not independent, so this is an **incorrect** answer.

Comment: Hi guys, i have fixed my answer. See if it makes sense now to you. Cheers and thanks.

Comment: Your first condition should be $f\left(\frac{1}{f(x)}\right)=x$. In my opinion, this is not really an answer, it is just rehashing the given condition.

Comment: Updated the answer with a simpler condition.

Comment: Updated the answer by deduction. Please take a look if interested.